# Vertical scroll bar html

Tags: html, css, angularjs

We are using Angular js and having difficulty in getting the native scroll bar aligned as per the table. The table is dynamic and is very big with lot of columns and rows. 
We have a parent div that holds many items along with this table. 
We need to use the browser scroll bar to find the horizontal scroll bar for the table and the same case for vertical too. we need to move the horizontal scroll bar to the right most end to view the vertical scroll bar. Due to which the app is not user friendly.

We were asked to provide a single scroll bar that extends as per the table. 
Attached the screenshot. 
Please provide if you have any suggestions.

I can provide the css if required[image].

CSS

```
        .scrollableDiv {
        height: 60%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .kpi-table td,
    .kpi-table th {
        padding: .50rem;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        border-top: 0;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    .kpi-table table,
    thead tr td {
        border: 1px solid white;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3!important;
    }
    .kpi-table table,
    thead {
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .kpi-table tbody {
        display: block;
        height: 40vh;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .kpi-table thead {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    .kpi-table thead {
        width: calc( 100% )
    }
    .kpi-table tbody {
        width: calc( 100% + 1.3em)
    }
    .kpi-table table {
        width: calc(100% + 50em);
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }


    <div class="scrollableDiv kpi-table table-responsive">
      <table id="maintable" [ngStyle]="{'width':getTableWidth()}" class="table-hover table-bordered" *ngIf="kpiLoaded">
        <thead id="maintablehead">
          .................................
        </thead>
        <tbody id="maintablebody" [ngStyle]="{'height':getTableBodyHeight()}" *ngIf="originalReportJSON">
          <tr *ngFor="let channel of filteredReportJSON | orderBy : 'source' : sortReverse ; let i = index">
            <td class="kpi-col-9 name" [ngStyle]="{'width':getFixedColWidth()}">{{s.name}}</td>
            <td class="kpi-col-9 source-name" [ngStyle]="{'width':getFixedColWidth()}">{{channel.source}}</td>
            <td [ngStyle]="{'width':getTableCellWidth()}" *ngFor="let kpi of channel.kpi | orderBy :'groupName'; let j = index" [hidden]="!getGroupDisplay(kpi.groupName)"
              [ngClass]="getClass(kpi.result)" (click)="kpi.result == 'na' ? true : setUpKPI(kpi,channel)" [attr.data-toggle]="kpi.result == 'na' ? '' : 'modal'"
              data-target="#myModal" (mouseover)="changeStyle($event,kpi.result)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event,kpi.result)" [attr.id]="'td'+'_'+i+'_'+j">
              {{kpi.result == 'na' ? 'NA' : kpi.percentage}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="col-xs-12 content-box loading" *ngIf="isLoading">
      </div>
      <div class="no-result" i18n=@@noresults *ngIf="! originalReportJSON">No Results</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: An html and CSS snippet would help here. Could you provide one.

Comment: Size of table is fixed or not? or please add html and CSS  with image so people can help you.

Comment: We will not be able to give you an appropriate answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Hi all,  Added the code. please let me know if any othe info is required

Comment: to be more clear, fix the elements on horizontal and vertical scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with updating html and css

Comment: Use comments section for very short answers